# SCP from server to local host failed

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp

I am sure I was SCPing some files TO the server before, but now it does not work in opposite direction.

I'm using:

```
$ scp -v mysrv:/home/XXX/dir/app.rb app.rb.bak

Authenticated to mysrv ([88.88.111.11]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
...
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: pledge: fork
subsystem request failed on channel 0
scp: Connection closed
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out in logs on the server that SFTP subsystem can not be found.

```
# journalctl -f
Jan 24 16:45:43 mysrv sshd[2045]: subsystem request for sftp by user XXX failed, subsystem not found
```

Don't know how it was disabled, but re-enabling it in config solved the issue.
Just uncomment one line..

```
# nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Don't forget to restart the SSHd.

```
# systemctl restart ssh
```

Just for search engine bots - here is the successfull SCP log:

```
Authenticated to mysrv ([88.88.111.11]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
...
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: pledge: fork
scp: debug1: Fetching /home/XXX/dir/app.rb to app.rb.bak

app.rb                                                                                                                                                                                                      100%   38KB 297.3KB/s   00:00    
scp: debug1: truncating at 39240
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3248, received 42336 bytes, in 1.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2528.5, received 32958.1
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: "Don't know how it was disabled" – It's possible it had never been enabled at all. It's possible an update of the *client* switched the default protocol `scp` uses from SCP to SFTP. I mean your `scp` used to use SCP and it worked ("I am sure I was SCPing some files TO the server before") and now it uses SFTP, so only now the `Subsystem sftp` config of the server matters for your `scp`. Please see "History, SCP and SFTP" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1733992/432690).

Comment: Y, I read your answer. It is possible. I'm just not sure, coz it's outdated (ubuntu 20) server I will get rid of so I thought maybe I disabled some options for security reasons.. Usually I have to enable SFTP subsystem for SCP to work. Anyway I did this just for ppl googling debug msgs. Your answer pops first anyway so they can try - but my macos's SCP does not have `-0` :)